# Azure AD SSO, IDP initiated login not working

Tags: azure, single-sign-on

I have created app in Azure AD, By following the below steps:

1 - Login to Azure AD, Click on Application tab, Add button.

2 - Select "Add an application my organization is developing".

3 - Select "Web applicaiton and/or web api".

4 - In Sign-in url give "https://mywebapplication.com/" and in APP ID URI inserted any random url.

5 - After application is created, gone to configure tab and give in reply url as "https://mywebapplication/saml2/acs/"

6 - I have configured this azure app in my web applicaiton, which supports saml 2.0.

The question is I am able to do SP initiated SSO. But can't do IDP initiated SSO. I don;t find any specific settings for IDP initiated SSO. I can see my application logo in access panel of azure ad (myapps.microsoft.com), on clicking it, it redirects to login page of web application instead of logging in the user.

Kindly help me in how can we perform IDP initiated SSO from Azure AD.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To Access the SSO feature of Azure AD , you need to add the Users in the Cloud Ad.Later On With the help of code , you can initiate a Session for specific users. 
You can go through this link to get the code samples shared by Microsoft..Also to better Manage your Users You have to learn the Azure Graph API

[Azure Active Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn646737.aspx#BKMK_Browser)

Comment: My web application is able to handle saml requests and responses, I am able to do SP initiated SSO. The problem is when I click on app icon from Access panel, It does not send saml response to my web application, instead it simply redirects user to login page of web application. It should login user to my web application, and at least send sample response.